# Nested Query, I think

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have a table with the following fields and example data:

```
user_id     meta_key           meta_value
-------     --------           ----------
'69'        'usertemplate'     'template1'
'69'        'userstartdate'    '07/26/2012 02:01:37 PM'
'69'        'userenddate'      '07/26/2013 02:01:37 PM'
'70'        'usertemplate'     'template1'
'70'        'userstartdate'    '07/26/2013 02:01:37 PM'
'70'        'userenddate'      '07/26/2014 02:01:37 PM'
'71'        'usertemplate'     'template2'
'71'        'userstartdate'    '07/26/2012 02:01:37 PM'
'71'        'userenddate'      '07/26/2013 02:01:37 PM'
'72'        'usertemplate'     'template2'
'72'        'userstartdate'    '07/26/2011 02:01:37 PM'
'72'        'userenddate'      '07/26/2012 02:01:37 PM'
'73'        'usertemplate'     'template2'
'73'        'userstartdate'    '07/25/2011 02:01:37 PM'
'73'        'userenddate'      '07/25/2012 02:01:37 PM'
```

My goal is to get a list of **user_id**s where (for example):

usertemplate = template2

userstartdate > 07/20/2011 02:01:37 PM

userstartdate < 07/30/2011 02:01:37 PM

How would I write this query?

edit:  This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM myTable t 
  INNER JOIN myTable s 
    ON t.user_id = s.user_id 
      AND s.meta_key = 'userstartdate' 
      AND CAST(s.meta_value AS DATE) > '07/20/2011 02:01:37 PM' 
  INNER JOIN myTable e 
    ON t.user_id = e.user_id 
      AND e.meta_key = 'userenddate' 
      AND CAST(e.meta_value AS DATE) < '07/30/2011 02:01:37 PM' 
WHERE t.meta_key = 'usertemplate' 
  AND t.meta_value = 'template2'
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle?

Comment: Have you tried to write the query yourself yet? Where are you stuck? What are you having problems with?

Comment: MySQL

I did try. but was way off..

SELECT user_id
FROM myTable t
INNER JOIN myTable s ON t.user_id = s.user_id 
    AND s.meta_key = 'userstartdate' 
    AND CAST(s.meta_value AS DATE) > '07/20/2011 02:01:37 PM'
INNER JOIN myTable e ON t.user_id = e.user_id 
    AND e.meta_key = 'userenddate' 
    AND CAST(e.meta_value AS DATE) < '07/30/2011 02:01:37 PM'
WHERE t.meta_key = 'usertemplate' AND t.meta_value = 'template2'

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a couple of self-joins:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM myTable t
INNER JOIN myTable s ON t.user_id = s.user_id 
    AND s.meta_key = 'userstartdate' 
    AND CAST(s.meta_value AS DATE) > '07/20/2011 02:01:37 PM'
INNER JOIN myTable e ON t.user_id = e.user_id 
    AND e.meta_key = 'userenddate' 
    AND CAST(e.meta_value AS DATE) < '07/30/2011 02:01:37 PM'
WHERE t.meta_key = 'usertemplate' AND t.meta_value = 'template2'
```

I will leave working out the exact syntax of the conversion to a date datatype and comparison as an exercise. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.user_id
 FROM tbl T
 INNER JOIN tbl T1
         on T.user_id = T1.user_id 
         AND T1.meta_key = 'usertemplate'
         AND T1.meta_value = 'template2'
 INNER JOIN tbl T2
         on T.user_id = T2.user_id 
         AND T2.meta_key = 'userstartdate'
         AND T2.meta_value > '07/20/2011 02:01:37 PM'   
         AND T2.meta_value < '07/30/2011 02:01:37 PM'
```